# Установка ssl сертификата для nginx docker, самый простой путь?

Tags: nginx, docker, ssl

Самый простой способ получить доступ по 443 порту в nginx docker, какой? `nginx:latest`

Мне в доверенные их даже добавлять и не нужно. Тут идея вот в чем, во первых я не фига не секу в TLS. Во вторых меня БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ устроит ситуация, когда браузер будет говорить - "Соединение не защищено, принять риск и продолжить". То есть доступ по 443 порту и протоколу HTTPS это все, что мне нужно.

Вот собственно самый самый простой путь для достижения этого в контейнере nginx в docker?

Comment: а в чем проблема/вопрос?

Comment: хочу иметь возможность зайти на сайт по 443 порту, подойдет даже вариант с надписью "сделать исключение для этого сайта", понимаете?)

Comment: `certbot --nginx`

Comment: @PakUula спасибо, а пару слов о нем если не трудно? введу я эту команду следующие действия? Почему все так в кратце?) Я дополнил свой вопрос если что

Comment: @DenisLopatin Добавил в качестве ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, ваш контейнер с `nginx` запущен. `docker ps` выдаёт что-то вроде

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
dcda1cbc1757   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   80/tcp    elated_austin
```

## Установка сертификатов для доменов

Изначально в вашем вопросе не было подробностей, поэтому я написал в комментарии про `certbot`. Для вашей задачи это оверкилл, поэтому можете сразу переходить ко второй части, про самоподписной сертификат.

Нужно "зайти внутрь" контейнера и установить в нём `certbot`, утилиту, которая устанавливает бесплатные сертификаты от [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

1. Подключитесь к контейнеру и запустите в нём `bash`: `docker exec -it dcda1cbc1757 bash`. Здесь `dcda1cbc1757` - идентификатор контейнера, напечатанный `docker ps`. У вас наверняка другой, замените.
2. Если идентификатор верный, и контейнер работает, то откроется строка ввода `bash` для пользователя `root`:

   ```
   root@dcda1cbc1757:/#
   ```
3. Надеюсь, у вас `nginx` запущен из образа `nginx:latest`, который собран на базе Debian. Тогде вам нужно обновить пакеты `apt` и установить `certbot`:

   ```sh
   apt update
   apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx -y
   ```

   Если у вас образ на базе `alpine`, то нужные пакеты устанавливаются командой `apk add certbot certbot-nginx`.
4. Запустите `certbot`: `certbot --nginx`
   Программа задаст вам пару вопросов, заставит принять пользовательское соглашение, затем проанализирует конфигурационные файлы `nginx` и спросит, для каких доменов запрашивать сертификаты.
5. Сертификаты и сопутствующие технический файлы будут сохранены в каталог `/etc/letsencrypt`. По-умолчанию этот каталог находится внутри контейнера, и сертификаты пропадут при пересоздании контейнера. Если вам нужно, чтобы они сохранялись, то перезапустите контейнер `nginx` и отмапьте этот каталог на файловую систему хоста: `docker run -v /path/in/host/fs:/etc/letsencrypt nginx:latest` (ну или как вы там запускаете).

## Установка сертификата для тестирования

Установить самоподписной сертификат

Нужно зайти в контейнер, чтобы сгенерировать сертификат и обновить конфигурационный файл `nginx`.

1. Зайти в контейнер: `docker exec -it dcda1cbc1757 bash`. Здесь `dcda1cbc1757` - идентификатор контейнера, напечатанный `docker ps`. У вас наверняка другой, замените.
2. В контейнере выполните команды

   ```sh
   cd /etc/nginx
   mkdir certs
   cd certs
   openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -x509 -days 365 -out server.crt
   ```

   Последняя команда задаст вам пяток вопросов об идентификации сертификата, сгенерирует ключ RSA длиной 2048 бит в файл `/etc/nginx/certs/server.key` и сертификат в файл `/etc/nginx/certs/server.crt`. Срок валидности сертификата 365 дней, ключ без пароля.
3. Установите какой-нибудь редактор, например `vim`: `apt install vim -y`
4. Отредактируйте настройки вашего сервера. В примере ниже редактируются настройки дефолтного сервера:

   ```sh
   editor /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
   ```

   Добавьте в параметры сервера `listen 443 ssl;` и пути к ключу и сертификату:

   ```
   server {
      listen       80;
      listen  [::]:80;
      listen  443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certs/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/server.key;
   ```

   Сохраните файл.
5. Перезагрузите `nginx`: `nginx -s reload`
6. Проверьте (прямо внутри контейнера): `curl -k https://localhost`
   Опция `-k` отключает проверку валидности сертификата.
   Если всё верно, `curl` напечатает содержимое `index.html` сервера

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
   <style>
   html { color-scheme: light dark; }
   body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, сначала я пробовал вариант №1, но как я понимаю, я не могу запросить сертификаты не подтвердив права на домен. Ну то есть, условно, я не могу запросить у Let's Encrypt сертификаты для доменов mvideo или ozon. Дело в том, что адреса доменов корректные и уже располагаются в сети, я же хотел поднять сервер локально, и все получилось, кроме tls соединения. Вариант №2 попробую чуть позже, но суть в том, что утилита openssl просто генерирует два самоподписанных сертификата на 365 дней в данном случае? Условно, я могу любой утилитой сгенерировать их и настроить nginx?

Comment: @DenisLopatin да, certbot проверяет, что у вас есть доступ к домену. Поэтому он не выдаст вам сертификат на чужой домен. Во втором варианте вы генерируете произвольный сертификат, но браузеры и прочие программы не примут его, так как он не имеет доверенный корневой сертификат. Вам нужно будет либо отключать проверки (например, curl -k) либо добавлять в исключения.

Comment: Ну браузеры должны позволить в таком случае принять риск и продолжить? Даже без добавления в доверенные

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой конфиг для nginx, может быть он поможет

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name myserverfit.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/serverKey.crt;

  ssl_verify_client off;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  glpat-RyCbALxj3_esK_pZbQbr

location /index {
    proxy_pass https://server:8085/index;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
  }

  location /hash-message {
    proxy_pass https://server:8085/hash-message;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Еще нужно добавить сертификаты в доверенные. На Windows это вроде делается легко, а если используете Linux придется поколдовать. Плюс надо в самом браузере также добавить сертификат как доверенный. Легче всего это делается в Google Chrome.

Comment: Нет, мне в доверенные их даже добавлять и не нужно. Тут идея вот в чем, во первых я не фига не секу в TLS. Во вторых меня БОЛЕЕ ЧЕМ устроит ситуация, когда браузер будет говорить - "Соединение не защищено, принять риск и продолжить". То есть доступ по 443 порту и протоколу HTTPS это все, что мне нужно. Отсюда возникает вопрос - могу ли я просто сгенерировать эти сертификаты и указать путь до них в nginx, да так, от балды как говорится. Или все несколько сложнее?