# SSL сертификат Docker Nginx

Tags: nginx, docker, ssl

сделал страничку comming soon на https://moasoap.ru/
Сделал ssl сертификат по инструкции https://azzrael.ru/docker-compose-nginx-https-selfsigned-cert

Почему то пишет что с сертификатом беда сайт не защищен
Подскажите пжс что делать или как можно сделать лучше docker-compose-file

Dockerfile - nginx

```
 
# apline based = ubuntu => apk istead apt
RUN apk update && apk add openssl
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && mkdir -p /home/web/www
 
RUN openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem 2048 &&\
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/certs/self.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/self.crt \
    -subj "/C=RU/ST=Saint-Petersburg /L=Saint-Petersburg /O=Moasoap/OU=Org/CN=moasoap.ru"
 
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d 
COPY ssl-params.conf /etc/nginx/ssl-params.conf
```

default.conf

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

upstream nextjs_upstream {
  server nextjs:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 ;

  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name moasoap.ru;

  # server_tokens off;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/self.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/self.key;
  include ssl-params.conf;
  root /home/web/www;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 4;
  gzip_types text/css application/javascript image/svg+xml;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location /_next/static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;

    # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
    # add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
  }

  location /static {
    proxy_cache STATIC;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_valid 60m;
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;

    # For testing cache - remove before deploying to production
    # add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }
}
```

ssl-params.conf

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
 
# Disable preloading HSTS for now. You can use the commented out header line that includes
# the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
#add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  nextjs:
    container_name: nextjs
    build: .
    restart: always #change if you don't want your container restarting
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
       - next-js-work

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/www/:/home/web/www
    networks:
      - next-js-work

networks:
   next-js-work:
    driver: bridge
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Решил благодаря данной инструкции
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538557/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-ssl-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-nginx-docker-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установка ssl сертификата для nginx docker, самый простой путь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538557/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-ssl-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-nginx-docker-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c)